# Can't install new program from zip file

Tags: zip

I'm new to ubuntu.

When I install some new program from a zip file, I get this message and can't install it.

```
Zipfile is disk 26970 of a multi-disk archive, and this is not the disk on
which the central zipfile directory begins (disk 16752).
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: On Ubuntu to install program you either need to use Ubuntu Software Center, install it from command line by entering ``sudo apt-get install packagename`` or find .deb file which you can double-click to install. Could you provide information about program that you want to install?

Comment: you can also compile a program from a source. But most importantly is that the file needs to be written fore Ubuntu and not Windows/Mac.

Comment: It would be more helpful to know what the file is and where you got it. From the error it appears that the zip file is one of a set. Obviously, the whole set is needed for decompression. Also, what program are you attempting to unzip it with?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded a zip file, you probably have a programs source code. To install that, you need to unzip it to a directory, `cd` into that directory, and run these commands:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

If that didn't work, you may want to check what you are downloading. There may be specific instructions for installation, or you may have downloaded the wrong file.